# Group a pandas df on variable columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have a dataframe which I want to aggregate as follows: I want to group by col1 and col6  and make a new column for col2 and col3.

```
col1     col2   col3   col6
a        it1    3      f
a        it2    5      f
b        it6    7      g
b        it7    8      g
```

I would like the result to look like this:

```
col1   col6  new_col
a      f     pd.DataFrame({"col2": ["it1", "it2"],"col3":[3,5]})
b      g     pd.DataFrame({"col2": ["it6", "it7"],"col3":[7,8]})
```

I tried the following:

```
def aggregate(gr):
     return(pd.DataFrame("col2":gr["col2"], "col3":gr["col3"]))
df.groupby("col1").agg(aggregate)
```

but aggregate seems not to be the right solution for this.
What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You want each cell in `new_col` to be a DataFrame?

Comment: I am converting the df to json right afterwards and want it to be grouped.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve so here are two ideas. First, if you are going to convert to json anyway, you can convert each group to json:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col6']).apply(lambda d: d.to_json())
```

produces

```
col1  col6
a     f       {"col1":{"0":"a","1":"a"},"col2":{"0":"it1","1...
b     g       {"col1":{"2":"b","3":"b"},"col2":{"2":"it6","3...
```

second, you *can* have dataframes inside a dataframe, here is how you can do that:

```
dd = {}
for idx, gr in df.groupby(['col1','col6']):
    dd[idx] = aggregate(gr)
dfout = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['newcol'], index = dd.keys())
for idx in dfout.index:
    dfout.at[idx, 'newcol'] = dd[idx]
```

Here is how it is printed with the help of the `tabulate` package:nicely:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(dfout, headers = 'keys'))

            newcol
----------  ------------
('a', 'f')     col2  col3
            0  it1     3
            1  it2     5
('b', 'g')     col2  col3
            2  it6     7
            3  it7     8
```

so has the right DataFrames inside `dfout`. When converted to json it looks like this:

```
dfout.to_json()
'{"newcol":{"(\'a\', \'f\')":{"col2":{"0":"it1","1":"it2"},"col3":{"0":3,"1":5}},"(\'b\', \'g\')":{"col2":{"2":"it6","3":"it7"},"col3":{"2":7,"3":8}}}}'
```